# Angular Template vs getter variable

Tags: angular, angular-template, angular2-changedetection

My code is working with getter variable, although it seems that it should work with plain predefined variable as well, which it doesn't. Here is the snippet:

```
@Component({
   selector: 'day-7days',
   templateUrl: './day-7days-view.component.html',
   changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class Day7DaysViewComponent extends DayView {

constructor(
    protected cdr: ChangeDetectorRef
   ) {
    super(cdr);
   }

  /**
  * implementation of an abstract function
  */
  public afterChanges() {
    /** does stuff ... */
    this.cdr.markForCheck();
  }

  public get selectedWeek(): Array<CalendarDay> {
    const w = this.shiftsToDays(this.weeks);
    const ww  = w.filter( (d: Array<CalendarDay>) => d[0].weekNumber === this.currentWeek);
    return this.cal.setLocationMeta(this.selectedLocation, ww).pop();
  }
}
```

If I get rid of that getter `selectedWeek` and set in within `afterChanges` method (which is called after `ngOnChanges` in the abstract class has run through) like this:

```
public afterChanges() {
   /** does stuff.. */
    const w = this.shiftsToDays(this.weeks);
    const ww  = w.filter( (d: Array<CalendarDay>) => d[0].weekNumber === this.currentWeek);
    this.selectedWeek = this.cal.setLocationMeta(this.selectedLocation, ww).pop();
    this.cdr.markForCheck();
}
```

it sets the variable initially, but after a change detection cycle has been initiated by a different component within the template, it gets reset to a state as though none of those methods (`shiftsToDays`, `filter`, `setLocationMeta`) has run before.
Any ideas why?

Having it as a `getter` works fine. My only concern is the performance.

Comment: are you sure you are calling afterChanges at the correct moment?

Comment: It is basically the only thing ngOnChanges does - calls afterChanges, which is implemented in every descendant component. ‍♂️

Comment: ah, then markForCheck is totally useless in this case, because afterChanges is called only during change detection. I bet this thing was in the code because somebody didn't understand how change detection works and that is the place to search, why it doesn't work after your change

Comment: are you mutating any of `this.weeks`, `this.cal` from outside? `ngOnChanges` is only called when some if `@Input`s are updated. if weeks is an array, and it is mutated - ngOnChanges won't becalled

Comment: hmm, I'll need to look into the mutation aspect, good point.

Comment: in parent `ngOnChanges` tried doing `this.weeks = this.weeks.slice()` to no avail. :/

Comment: most likely something is mutated somewhere, that is why ngOnChanges isnt called and calculated value isn't updated